# Flask not working inside virtualenv

Tags: pip, virtualenv

Needed to debug python 3 on Mac, so I installed it through Homebrew, and created virtualenv like this:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3 Flask3
```

But after installing Flask using pip:

```
source /Flask3/bin/activate
sudo pip install flask
```

Python says I don't have Flask. Why?

UPD: Info about my virtualenv:

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
/Users/anton/Flask3/bin/python
pip 1.5 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
Python 3.3.3
```

Comment: are you sure the activation worked? run 'pip freeze' after the installation to see what libraries you have installed. it should show flask. if not, is there an error for 'pip install flask'? Also, don't use sudo with pip. install on your user 'pip install flask' without the sudo, which always causes problems with flask. no reason to use sudo here.

Comment: @GG_Python Flask==0.10.1

Comment: try without sudo. i would remove the virtualenv entirely first (deactivate, then 'rm -rf /Flask3'). also, take into account i'm not on mac, and for my what worked is pyvenv-3.4 instead of virtualenv. try to see if you can find mac-specific instructions for python3/ virtualenv. It's not quite the same as with python 2.

Comment: activate your virtualenv, what is the output of `which pip`, `which python`?; check `pip --version` and `python --version` as well

Comment: also, use `pyvenv` instead of `virtualenv` with `Python 3`